# LinqToDB: How to change connection string, or set it without using project's configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq2db

https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db
I need to use different connection strings and can't find how to make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. It's not very nice. (I use `firebird`):

```
public FirebirdDatabaseContext(IDataProvider provider, string connectionString):base(provider, connectionString){}
```

Used an overload with `IDataProvider`. When creating a `FirebirdDatabaseContext` need to directly pass `new FirebirdDataProvider()` as first argument, and a connection string as second.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataConnection.AddConfiguration(...)` and `DataConnection.SetConnectionString(...)` to add new or change existing connection strings in linq2db.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide different connection strings as long as you gave them different names:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=yourdatabasesource;User ID=User;Password=Yourpassword" />

 <add name="Northwind" 
    connectionString = "Server=.\;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;Enlist=False;" 
    providerName     = "SqlServer" />

</connectionStrings>
```

**EDIT 1:**

---

Another way to do it , is to create an external config file and reference it in your `web.config`.

- In your solution , add a new config file and create all of your connection strings (**This file should have only the connection string syntax and nothing else**):

  `<connectionStrings>
      Conenction name 1
      Connection name 2
      ......
      </connectionStrings>`
- In your web.config reference to this config file :

  `<connectionStrings configSource="Youconfigfilename.config"></connectionStrings>`

Comment: I don't want to place over 200 connection string in config, because they differ only by ID.

Comment: You can create a config file , where you can store all of your connection strings and reference it once in your web.config
Check my edits